# Calculating Values of ADC for Phototransistor on Digital Pin

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, adc, phototransistor

I would like to read a phototransistor from a digital GPIO pin on Raspberry Pi or Arduino microcontroller. Phototransistors are analog devices and to read the value properly I know that I will need an ADC. There are many ADC that would do this for me just fine; however, I am looking for the most cost effective solution. This when I came across this [reflectance sensor](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J13/2) from Pololu. Here you can see the following schematic (along with some additional details):

[image: ADC Circuit with Phototransistor]

This schematic allows you to interact with this sensor on a digital pin of a microcontroller. I would like to modify this circuit to fit my application of just a phototransistor. My question comes into play of how to calculate my necessary values for the resistor and capacitor. If anyone could give me some direction of where to start that would great!

If anyone has any additional questions I would be happy to provide additional information.

Based off some questions I received here is what I am thinking the circuit will look like:

[image: Phototransistor with Capacitor and Resistor]

Since it is not a reflectance sensor I can just remove the diode and current limiting resistor. Now comes the question on how to calculate the proper values for R1 and C1. I plan on using the [TEPT5600](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vishay-semiconductor-opto-division/TEPT5600/1681192) phototransistor.

The other question was the environment the sensors would be located in. The sensor would be placed in an area that would be relatively dark experience a minimum Lux of around 1 to 5 and maximum of around 300.

Comment: You need to show us a schematic of your proposed modified circuit. Include links to the manufacturer's datasheet for the phototransistor. Explain exactly how the phototransistor will be illuminated in your application, and what exactly you hope to detect or measure with the circuit.

Comment: something is wrong with the phototransistor part of the circuit, there is no place for it to get current so the value will always be zero on the output.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I think this is some kind of crude ADC formed by charging the capacitor with the GPIO (as output) and then allowing the PT to discharge it (as digital input) whilst counting microseconds or whatever.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Interesting. There definitely has to be something more than just the circuit above. I think if your one starting out, a pullup would be better to work with like you suggested.

Comment: what's wrong with the built-in ADC? Talk about simple and cost-effective...

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have made some edits to fill in some of your questions

Comment: @dandavis Raspberry Pi does not have any built in ADC and and Arduino only has 6 ports. I looking at ways to potentially connect hundreds. That is why I looking at very rudimentary methods.

Comment: might consider a shift register to provide power, which would let you put several on one GPIO. i don't think the digital method would be very precise because the high/low voltage thresholds can vary per-pin and with temp, making calibration difficult if you need more than just "it's dark or not".

Comment: @dandavis It is possible that could work, because I am basically looking to detect if something is in front of sensor or not which is basically "it's dark or not"

Comment: fair enough. in that case yeah, using your above circuit and a PISO shift register you can read 8-16 on/offs per pin at a decent frequency. Just feed the "Out"s to the SR's INs, then read the value. Or use a SIPO SR to power each of the circuits individually and read the value of the currently powered one with a plain old GPIO.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I will look more into that. However, I will add (this is not your fault) still do not know how to calculate what value of a resistor or capacitor I need for the proposed circuit which is ultimately my question.

Comment: With an ADC you have 1024 possible levels you can measure so the transition point can practically vary over a wide  range. Using digital input you have to get the resistor value correct for each input. While you could have a large number of trimpots, that sounds a bit ugly.

Comment: The capacitor charge/discharge method outlined by Pololu has a very wide dynamic range (greater than a 10-bit ADC), since it uses time-counting methods with no inherent limit on counter length. But the ADC-with-sense-resistor method has better accuracy. Leakage current of GPIO digital input limits low-light end...spec sheet may say 1uA, but a measurement @ 23 degrees C was less than 1nA. You can use a 100pF cap instead of 10nF for more sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a resistor to Vdd of your microcontroller (maybe).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feg1w3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor should be high enough to give the desired sensitivity but not higher than your ADC can tolerate (usually a few K up to 10K).

To get some idea of whether this will work, measure the photocurrent under the desired range of conditions.

Comment: depending on values, this can be simplified by replacing 3.3v+R1 with a GPIO in Arduino's INPUT_PULLUP mode. Might even be able to use the same GPIO to read as used to "power" it; they switch pretty quickly...

Comment: Thanks Spehro. I have thought about doing something like this. The only problem is that the value of the resistor is highly dependent about the surrounding area. I worry that the sensor would work well in some areas and wouldn't work in other areas that have different light. I am still will probably attempt this, but looking for other possibilities.

Comment: @dandavis If the tolerances are acceptable (they are somewhere between 20K and 50K on the Microchip ATmega328p).

Comment: @Mitch Not sure what you are expecting. You have 10 bits of ADC, if you need more dynamic range then consider a digital light sensor where someone else has done the hard engineering for  you.

Comment: Yea, that is an option I am exploring as well. There is a few cheap light sensors that incorporate an i2c interface that I am also testing. I am just trying to exhaust all my options

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful graph from page 3 of the [TEPT5600 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84768/tept5600.pdf) you pointed us to:

[image]

From this we can tell what collector currents to expect when illuminated with 3 lux or 300 lux. Extrapolating to the left a bit, 3 lux seems to correspond to about 10μA, and 300 lux gets you about 1mA.

From there, we know how fast a capacitor will charge given a certain illumination. The following equation relating current through and voltage across a capacitor is apposite:

$$ i = C\frac{dV}{dt} $$

Assuming a constant current:

$$ \Delta t = \frac{C\Delta V}{i} $$

Then we assume that the capacitor must go from fully discharged (0V across it) to roughly half of the supply voltage (probably slightly more), to register as a change in GPIO digital logic level. For a 5V Arduino that's \$\frac{5}{2}=2.5V\$, and for a 3.3V Raspberry pi it would be \$\frac{3.3}{2}=1.7V\$. For the estimates I make here, \$\Delta V = 2V\$ is close enough, but you'll have to experiment.

We need to find out how long it will take a capacitor to charge to 2V, given currents of 10uA (at 3 lux) and 1mA (at 300 lux) through it. Assuming (there are a lot of assumptions) a capacitance of 10nF, as Pololu suggests:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta t_{3lux} &= \frac{10nF \times 2V}{10\mu A} \\ \\
&= 2ms
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta t_{300lux} &= \frac{10nF \times 2V}{1mA} \\ \\
&= 20\mu s
\end{aligned}
$$

Whatever software you write for the microprocessor will need to be be able to discern delays in the tens of microseconds. Easy for a Raspberry pi, not so easy for a 16MHz Arduino, but still feasible.

If needed, you can extend the pulse lengths by increasing the capacitance. Using 100nF, a factor of ten increase, will yield charge times ten times longer; 20ms and 200μs respectively.

Don't forget that the initial high output pulse to discharge the capacitor will have to be about \$5 \times R \times C = 5 \times 220 \times C\$, to ensure the capactitor is 99% discharged. For C=10nF that's about 10μs, or if c=100nF, 100μs or so.